# Interaction plot - overlapping order

Tags: r, plot, interaction

Say, I have a data frame like this

```
"hours" "environment" "humidity"
"1" 360 "cold" "dry"
"2" 360 "cold" "dry"
"3" 372 "intermediate" "dry"
"4" 420 "intermediate" "wet"
"5" 456 "warm" "wet"
"6" 432 "warm" "wet"
```

As you can see I have a file (bread.txt) with 2 samples for every value of *environment* (cold,intermediate,warm). I want to create an interaction plot where I have 2 samples and for each sample it plots the *hours* against the *environment*. The closest I've been so far is

```
r=rep(1:6)
interaction.plot(r,bread$environment,bread$hours)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution with `ggplot()`:

```
library(ggplot2)
test <- data.frame(hours=c(360, 360, 372,
                           420, 456, 432),
                   environment=c("cold", "cold", "intermediate",
                                 "intermediate", "warm", "warm"),
                   humidity=c("dry", "dry", "dry",
                              "wet", "wet", "wet"))
# Add a factor allowing to distinguish between the first and the second sample
test$rep <- rep(1:2)
# plot
ggplot(data=test) +
    geom_line(aes(x=rep, y=hours, color=environment))
```

Here is the result:[image]